# Scala backticks in Play Framework Routes

Tags: scala, ember.js, playframework, playframework-2.4, scala-2.11

I am using Ember.js and Play for a single page web app with Play as the API.  Ember coalesces requests like this, `?ids[]=401460&ids[]=379610`.  But when I try handle that value in Play's routes file it is literally expecting the value as `ids[]` instead of  `ids`.  But I can't tell the routes file to look for `ids[]` because it throws errors on `[`.   I have tried using back ticks like I would in scala code itself `` `ids[]` `` but that again throws errors in the routes file.

Is it possible to do this in the routes file?

```
GET /api/test      controllers.application.getTests(ids[]:List[Long])
```

I know I can manage it this way,

```
 Map<String,String[]> params = request().body().asFormUrlEncoded();
```

But I would prefer to just let Play do its thing and handle it in the routes file then hand the value off.

Is this at all possible or are the only options to handle it using `asFormUrlEncoded`?

<del>**Update:** (Work around with minimal changes)</del>

<del>While playing around with it some more I stumbled upon the fact that even though I can't add it to the list of query string parameters in the routes file, it is still passed along to the function.  

So if you are using Ember or some other JS library or Framework that coalesces with [] in the name, and are not using the newest Play.  Unfortunately this makes the route ambiguous while reading the routes file since you cant tell that it is expecting a value, but its works until Play 2.5 becomes Prod ready.  You can handle it this way,</del>

Never mind about that work around.  Forgetting to save a file before re trying gave me some false hope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this isn't possible in Play 2.4.x. There is [a test in `RoutesFileParserSpec.scala`](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/routes-compiler/src/test/scala/play/routes/compiler/RoutesFileParserSpec.scala#L110-L113) that suggests it's possible:

```
"parse argument with complex name" in {
  parseRoute("GET /s p.c.m(`b[]`: List[String] ?= [])").call.parameters must_== Some(Seq(
    Parameter("`b[]`", "List[String]", None, Some("[]"))))
}
```

But it looks like you'll have to wait for 2.5.x. See also this issue: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/4693

Comment: Note that 2.5.0-M1 is available https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/CRWoluub3a8

Comment: Thanks for finding that and letting me know it will be supported in 2.5.  And since my question was specific to 2.4 this is the answer.  Not the one I was hoping for but the answer.  Thanks for the help.